# How to get list of all window handles in Java (Using JNA) on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, jna

I have been using the JNA library to get all visible window handles in Windows.  I need to do something similar in macOS using JNA.

Here is code to get all window handles in Windows:

```
 public static List<HWND> findAll() {
    final List<HWND> windows = new LinkedList<>();
    User32.INSTANCE.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
        @Override
        public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg) {
            if (User32.INSTANCE.IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
                windows.add(hWnd);
            }
            return true;
        } 
    }, null);
    return windows;
}
```

What is the equivalent code in macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to map portions of the [Core Graphics Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics?language=objc).  You can list windows using the [CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo?language=objc) function.

To load the framework you'll need to map a `CoreGraphics` interface extending JNA's `Library` class, and map the function you need:

```
public interface CoreGraphics extends Library {
    CoreGraphics INSTANCE = Native.load("CoreGraphics", CoreGraphics.class);

    CFArrayRef CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(int option, int relativeToWindow);
}
```

The `CFArrayRef` type is already mapped in JNA in the [`CoreFoundation`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/mac/CoreFoundation.html) class. Pick the appropriate [Window List Option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/window_list_option_constants?language=objc) (probably `kCGWindowListOptionAll` = 0).  If you already had a window number you could use relative reerences, otherwise you'll use `kCGNullWindowID` (0) for the second parameter. Calling it from your code should be simple:

```
CFArrayRef windowInfo = CoreGraphics.INSTANCE.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(0, 0);
```

That will give you an array of `CFDictionaryRef` objects representing the windows.  You can iterate the array and then use further methods in the [`CFDictionaryRef`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/mac/CoreFoundation.CFDictionaryRef.html) class to explore these dictionary objects: you'll create a `CFString` for the keys.  A list of required keys is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/required_window_list_keys?language=objc) and optional keys are [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/optional_window_list_keys?language=objc).  The constant strings [match the variable name](https://www.monkeybreadsoftware.net/module-cgwindowmbs.shtml).

This should get you a `CFNumberRef` for each window number (the "handle" equivalent):

```
// Set up keys for dictionary lookup
CFStringRef kCGWindowNumber = CFStringRef.createCFString("kCGWindowNumber");
CFStringRef kCGWindowOwnerPID = CFStringRef.createCFString("kCGWindowOwnerPID");
// Note: the Quartz name is rarely used
CFStringRef kCGWindowName = CFStringRef.createCFString("kCGWindowName");
CFStringRef kCGWindowOwnerName = CFStringRef.createCFString("kCGWindowOwnerName");

// Iterate the array
int numWindows = windowInfo.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < numWindows; i++) {
    // For each array element, get the dictionary
    Pointer result = windowInfo.getValueAtIndex(i);
    CFDictionaryRef windowRef = new CFDictionaryRef(result);

    // Now get information from the dictionary.

    // Get a pointer to the result, in this case a CFNumber
    result = windowRef.getValue(kCGWindowNumber);
    // "Cast" the pointer to the appropriate type
    CFNumberRef windowNumber = new CFNumberRef(result);
    // CoreFoundation.INSTANCE.CFNumberGetType(windowNumber)
    // --> 4 = kCFNumberSInt64Type, signed 64 bit so use getLong()
    
    // Get a pointer to the result, in this case a CFNumber
    result = windowRef.getValue(kCGWindowOwnerPID);
    // "Cast" the pointer to the appropriate type
    CFNumberRef windowOwnerPID = new CFNumberRef(result);
    // CoreFoundation.INSTANCE.CFNumberGetType(windowOwnerPID)
    // --> 4 = kCFNumberSInt64Type, signed 64 bit so use getLong()

    // Get a pointer to the result, in this case a CFString
    result = windowRef.getValue(kCGWindowName);
    // "Cast" the pointer to the appropriate type
    // Optional key, check for null
    String windowName = result == null ? "" : new CFStringRef(result).stringValue();

    // Get a pointer to the result, in this case a CFString
    result = windowRef.getValue(kCGWindowOwnerName);
    // "Cast" the pointer to the appropriate type
    // Optional key, check for null
    String windowOwnerName = result == null ? "" : new CFStringRef(result).stringValue();

    // ... look up other keys if needed ...
    // use ProcessHandle with the PID to get start time

    // Output or add to List, etc.
    System.out.println(windowNumber.longValue() 
        + " (" + windowOwnerName + ", pid=" 
        + windowOwnerPID.longValue()
        + "): " + windowName);
}

// CF references from "Copy" or "Create" must be released
// release the created key references
kCGWindowNumber.release();
kCGWindowOwnerPID.release();
kCGWindowName.release();
kCGWindowOwnerName.release();
// release the array
windowInfo.release();
```

Comment: What about CoreGraphics ? CoreGraphics is also in JNA?

Comment: You will create your own class extending `Library`. I included the syntax in my answer.

Comment: How can I get Window Name(title), Process Name, Process Id  and Process Start time?

Comment: The window name is in that information dictionary using the key `kCGWindowName`. The owning process name is at the key `kCGWindowOwnerName`.  The owning process id is at `kCGWindowOwnerPID`.  To get start time you'd use the PID to get the `ProcessHandle` in Java 9+.

Comment: CFStringRef kCGWindowName = CFStringRef.createCFString("kCGWindowName");

Comment: Pointer windowName = windowRef.getValue(kCGWindowName);

Comment: Thanks for help and time..Hopefully this will work on mac @Daniel Widdis

Comment: I've updated the example with the code necessary for the added fields.  Note: all my window names are empty/null, but the other stats are as expected

Comment: Can I check if process/window is alive or not by pid using JNA ?..

Comment: If you are on JDK9+ the ProcessHandle class in Java is the best way to identify a running process.  You can create it with the PID.  The dictionaries identified in the answer include telling you the layer (front or back) and whether it is displayed.