# How to get foreground window/process in Java (Using JNA) on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, jna

Currently, I am working to get foreground(top) window/process in MS Windows. I need to do something similar in macOS using JNA.

What is the equivalent code in macOS?

```
  byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
  PointerType hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();  
  User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
  System.out.println(Native.toString(windowText));
```

Comment: But note: I would first stop thinking about java here. Try to figure how you normally do such things in MacOs ... and then see how the elements you find can/are represented towards java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two questions here, foreground window and foreground process.  I'll try to answer both.

---

For the foreground *process* an easy way using JNA is to map [Application Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices) API.  Note that these functions were introduced in 10.9 and are now deprecated, but still work as of 10.15.  The newer version is in the `AppKit` Library, see below.

Create this class, mapping the two functions you'll need:

```
public interface ApplicationServices extends Library {
    ApplicationServices INSTANCE = Native.load("ApplicationServices", ApplicationServices.class);

    int GetFrontProcess(LongByReference processSerialNumber);
    int GetProcessPID(LongByReference processSerialNumber, IntByReference pid);
}
```

The "foreground" process can be obtained with [`GetFrontProcess()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1501050-getfrontprocess?language=objc).  That returns something called a `ProcessSerialNumber`, a unique 64-bit value used throughout the Application Services API.  To translate it for your userspace use, you probably want the Process ID, and [`GetProcessPID()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1500992-getprocesspid?language=objc) does that translation for you.

```
LongByReference psn = new LongByReference();
IntByReference pid = new IntByReference();
ApplicationServices.INSTANCE.GetFrontProcess(psn);
ApplicationServices.INSTANCE.GetProcessPID(psn, pid);
System.out.println("Front process pid: " + pid.getValue());
```

---

While the above works, it is deprecated. A new application should use the `AppKit` Library:

```
public interface AppKit extends Library {
    AppKit INSTANCE = Native.load("AppKit", AppKit.class);
}
```

There are multiple other StackOverflow questions regarding the topmost application using this library, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348627/what-is-the-correct-way-to-identify-the-currently-active-application-in-osx-10).  Mapping all the imports and objects needed is far more work than I have time to do in an answer here, but you might find it useful.  It's probably easier to figure out how to use the [Rococoa framework](https://github.com/iterate-ch/rococoa) (which uses JNA under the hood but has already mapped all of AppKit via JNAerator) to access this API.  Some [javadocs are here](http://jnaerator.sourceforge.net/sites/rococoa-auto/apidocs/org/rococoa/cocoa/appkit/package-summary.html).

There are also [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613293/how-to-get-name-of-frontmost-app-with-applescript-and-use-it-to-get-the-filepath) using `AppleScript` that you can execute from Java via command line using `Runtime.exec()` and capturing output.

---

With regard to foreground *window* on the screen, it's a bit more complicated.  In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63417421/1161484) to your earlier question on iterating all windows on macOS, I answered how to get a list of all the windows using `CoreGraphics` via JNA, including a `CFDictionary` containing more information.

One of those dictionary keys is [`kCGWindowLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgwindowlayer?language=objc) which will return a `CFNumber` representing the window layer number. The docs state this is 32-bit, so `intValue()` is appropriate.  The number is the "drawing order" so a higher number will overwrite a lower number.  So you can iterate over all the retrieved windows and find the maximum number.  This will be the "foreground" layer.

There are some caveats:

- There are actually only 20 layers available.  Many things share a layer.
- Layer 1000 is the screensaver. You can ignore layers 1000 and higher.
- Layer 24 is the Dock, usually on top, with Layer 25 (the icons on the dock) at a higher level.
- Layer 0 appears to be the rest of the desktop.
- Which window is "on top" depends on where on the screen you look.  Over the dock, the dock will be in the foreground (or the application icon).  On the rest of the screen, you need to check the pixel you're evaluating vs. the screen rectangle obtained from the CoreGraphics window.  (Use the `kCGWindowBounds` key which returns a `CGRect` (a structure with 4 doubles, X, Y, width, height).

You will need to filter to onscreen windows.  If you already fetched the list you could use the [`kCGWindowIsOnscreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgwindowisonscreen?language=objc) key to determine whether the window is visible.  It returns a `CFBoolean`.  Since that key is optional you will need to test for `null`.  However, if you are starting from nothing, it would be better to use the `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` [Window Option Constant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services/window_list_option_constants?language=objc) when you initially call [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo?language=objc).

In addition to iterating *all* windows, the [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo?language=objc) function takes a [`CGWindowID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgwindowid?language=objc) parameter `relativeToWindow` and you can add (with bitwise or) `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenAboveWindow` to the options.

Finally, you might find that limiting to windows associated with the current session may be useful, and you should map [`CGWindowListCreate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1552209-cgwindowlistcreate?language=objc) using similar syntax to the `CopyInfo()` variant.  It returns an array of window numbers that you could limit your dictionary search to, or pass that array as an argument to [`CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455215-cgwindowlistcreatedescriptionfro?language=objc).

As mentioned in my previous answer, you "own" every object you create using `Create` or `Copy` functions, and are responsible for releasing them when you are done with them, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I have find the maximum number..But it not foreground window..Why is so? Any idea?

Comment: It always return same layer number..Even I have changed foreground but layer number remain same..

Comment: This problem occur when I switch already open program/process. For example, text editor and Ms word both open. Currently, Ms word is active then my program will show  Ms word but when I switch to text editor. Program show Ms word not text editor..What is issue?

Comment: OK, there is another API, `ApplicationServices` that can give you more info.  Editing my answer.

Comment: Can you help to get foreground window using ApplicationServices api ?

Comment: OK, I've updated with ApplicationServices API that works as of 10.15, but no guarantees for the future. Correct solution is AppKitLibrary API, but that is far too much work for me to do in a SO answer, you'll have to take that one on yourself.

Comment: The Native.load method was not able to find AppKitLibray. I changed the code to: Native.load("AppKit", AppKitLibrary.class); and it worked.

Comment: @Esses77 thanks for the correction. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
   AppleScriptEngine appleEngine = new apple.applescript.AppleScriptEngine();
    ArrayList<String> processNames = null;
    try {
        String processName = null;
        processNames = (ArrayList<String>) appleEngine
                .eval("tell application \"System Events\" to get name of application processes whose frontmost is true and visible is true");
        if (processNames.size() > 0) {
            processName = processNames.get(0);// the front most process name
        }
        return processName;
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        log.debug("no app running");
    }
```

Comment: Hello, great that you took the time to answer the question. Please add some more text to help other explain what you have done and any possible modifications OP has to do in order to apply the solution.